# Python2.7 - Incorrect output when iterating through string index and printing only even or odd index value

Tags: python, indexing

When iterating through a string and printing only the value of the even string index, Python is printing the value at string.index(3) even though I'm asking it to only print the value if the index is even.  I would like to know why this is happening.  Here is the code I have been using:

```
    my_string = 'Hello, World!'
    for i in my_string:
        if my_string.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            print i
        else:
            print my_string.index(i)
```

When we run the code, it should return:

```
H
1
l
3
o
5

7
o
9
l
11
!
```

However, Python is returning:

```
H
1
l
l 
o
5

7
o
9
l
11
!
```

As you can see, the 'l' at index[3] is being returned instead of 3.

This seems to be the case in every interpreter I use so I'm assuming it's a problem with Python.  Is there some way to fix this?  Is it happening for anyone else?  This seems like it could be a very big issue if someone is writing a program that needs to separate even and odd indexes accurately.

Comment: Sorry, I spelled iterating incorrectly in the title.

Comment: Yes, I know that Python starts counting at 0.  At index 3 of the string, there is an 'l'.  The 'l' should not be printed in accordance with my code.  I'm asking the interpreter to only display the values of each even index..

Comment: The `index` method is independent of any iterator currently being used with the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.index` doesn't do what you think it does - it returns the *first* index. In your case you have:

```
 Hello... # text
 01234    # indices
```

The first index of `l` is `2`. Which is even, and not displayed. What you want to use instead is `enumerate`:

```
my_string = 'Hello, World!'
for i, char in enumerate(my_string):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print char
    else:
        print i
```

If you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) you'll see that:

> s.index(x) |  index of the first occurrence of x in s

You can also try this way:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
>>> help('hello'.index)
Help on built-in function index:

index(...)
    S.index(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Like S.find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
```

(which should lead you to

```
>>> help('hello'.find)
Help on built-in function find:

find(...)
    S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

> **lowest index in S**

In `'Hello, World!'` the *lowest* index for `l` is 2. The lowest index of `o` is 4. If you took your code and flipped the logic to `if i % 2:` then you'll see that you get `4` for the second `o`!

Comment: If our answers were any more similar, I'd yell "Jinx!". Even our hats are the same. You did beat me by 16 seconds, though.

Comment: Ruawahrrrh rawwrh rawwrhhr (For those coming to this after the winter bash, that's Abominable Snowman speak)

Comment: Both of you have the i/c reversed

Comment: Ok, this is happening just because there are two l's next to each other?  Seems a little confusing, but cool.  I'm sure I can work with it.  Thanks for the answer.  :)

Comment: The problem is *apparent* because two l's next to each other are guaranteed to have different "parity" (one will be even, the other odd). The third l only "works" because it happens to be in an even position just like the first one. You would see a wrong result if you had made a typo and processed the string `Hello, Wolrd!` as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `.index` returns the index of the *first* matching character (or the start of the first matching substring), not the currently iterated position. Since `"Hello"` has 2 `l` characters, the `my_string.index('l')` will always return 2, and as an even number, the character is printed instead of index.

What you need is [the builtin function **`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), which yields pairs of `index, item` for each item in the given iterable:

```
my_string = 'Hello, World!'
for index, char in enumerate(my_string):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        print(char)
    else:
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 2):

`index` returns the index of the *first* occurrence of its argument; `l` occurs three in `Hello, World!`, but `my_string.index('l')` always returns 2.

Use `enumerate` instead:

```
for i, c in enumerate(my_string):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print c
    else:
        print i
```

Comment: Both of you have the i/c reversed

Comment: Indeed; one problem with using `i` to refer to a character and not an index.

Comment: I get it now.  Thanks for the input.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating on the sting itself, try iterating on range(len(my_string)).  The full instruction would be:
  for i in range(len(my_string):
This will step every number from 0 to one less than the number of characters in the string. You can then use i to slice your string to get the individual character. You can also use the other the other inputs to the range function to specify where to start (default=0) and step size (default=1).
  As for the rest, use i % 2 == 0 in your if statement, print i to print the index, and print my_string[i] to print the character.